# Install old QtCreator on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to build my application on Ubuntu. The last versions have been tested and programmed under Windows, because it is a multiplatform application.
Sadly, under Ubuntu the systray icon did not work as I tried to compile on Ubuntu (the icon appeared next to the launcher). The icon is a must-have for my application.

I've heard this comes from the version of Qt, since 5.0 the SniQt that makes an AppIndicator would not work any more.
So I figured, if I compile my application with Qt 4.x, it must work.

But how do I install this "old" version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [QT5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt5&searchon=names) and [QT4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=qt4&searchon=names) are in main Ubuntu repository for 14.04

You can simply install QT4 as

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-default libqt4-dev qtchooser qt4-designer
```